# How to Configure FlashPlayer10.3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash, flashplayer-10

i am using flash CS4 for my flash projects. now how can i export swf for Flash player 10.3 i have downloaded flashplayer_inc_playerglobal_051211.swc from http://www.bytearray.org/?p=3066
but i dont know how to use it. will you pls guide me.

Thanx.

by the response from George Profenza i have followed instruction from http://blog.kaourantin.net/?p=104 but when i publish swf for Flash Player 11 it opens following screen.

Is anybody have similar issue???????????

Pls help.
[image]

FlashPlayer11.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <players>
      <player id="FlashPlayer11" version="13" asversion="3">
       <name>Flash Player 11</name>
       <path builtin="true"/>
       <path platform="WIN">Device Central/adcdl.exe</path>
       <path platform="MAC">Device Central/adcdl</path>
       <playerDefinitionPath as2="$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP10;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP9;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP8;$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP7" as3="$(AppConfig)/ActionScript 3.0/FP11/playerglobal.swc" />
       <feature name="multiScreenPublish"               supported="true" />
       <feature name="mobileAuthoringIntegration"           supported="true" />
       <feature name="deviceSound"                  supported="false"/>
       <feature name="exportStreamingSound"         supported="true"/>
       <feature name="exportEventSound"             supported="true"/>
       <feature name="FSCommand2"                   supported="false"/>
       <feature name="gradient_linearRGB"           supported="true" />
       <feature name="gradient_overflow"            supported="true" />
       <feature name="shape_strokeHint"             supported="true" />
       <feature name="shape_cap"                supported="true" />
       <feature name="shape_join"               supported="true" />
       <feature name="shape_mitre"              supported="true" />
       <feature name="shape_scale"              supported="true" />
       <feature name="linkage_exportForActionscript"    supported="true" />
       <feature name="linkage_exportForRuntimeSharing"  supported="true" />
       <feature name="linkage_exportInFirstFrame"       supported="true" />
       <feature name="linkage_importForRuntimeSharing"  supported="true" />
       <feature name="linkage_importAndAddToCache"      supported="false" />
       <feature name="publish_localPlaybackSecurity"    supported="true" />
       <feature name="publish_hardwareAcceleration"     supported="true" />
       <feature name="symbol_blendMode"             supported="true" /> 
       <feature name="actionScript_documentClass"       supported="true" />
       <feature name="symbol_blendMode"             supported="true" />
       <feature name="filters"              supported="true" />
       <feature name="component_binding"            supported="true" />
       <feature name="component_schema"             supported="true" />
       <feature name="screens"              supported="true" />
       <feature name="video"                supported="true" />
       <feature name="deviceVideo"              supported="false"/>
       <feature name="accessibility"            supported="true" />
       <feature name="dynamic_text_kerning"         supported="true" />
       <feature name="static_text_charwidth_nondeviceFont"  supported="true" /> 
       <feature name="static_text_charwidth_deviceFont" supported="true" />
       <feature name="advanced_anti_alias_text"         supported="true" /> 
       <feature name="nine_slice_scaling"           supported="true" />
       <feature name="runtimeNumberMinMax"          supported="true" />
       <feature name="use8kSampleRate"                      supported="true" />
       <feature name="useDefineFont4ForDeviceText"          supported="true" />
       <feature name="useDefineFont4ForEmbeddedFonts"       supported="true" />
       <feature name="textLayoutFramework"       supported="true" />
       <encodingPresets>
            <preset uuid="da5cac1a-417a-4d86-b7f7-ef21010a5d7d"  name="FLV - Match Source Attributes (High Quality)" ext="flv" default="true"/>
        </encodingPresets>

       <testmenu> 
        <menu name="ID_testInFlash" default="true"/>
        <menu name="ID_testInDeviceCentral" />
       </testmenu>

       <debugmenu>
        <menu name="ID_debugtInFlash" default="true"/> 
        <menu name="ID_debugInDeviceCentral"/> 
      </debugmenu>


       </player>
    </players>
```

One new thing i find out when you debug movie it will export swf in flash player but when i tested following ActionScript code it displays incorrect details.

```
trace(Capabilities.version);
trace(Capabilities.playerType);

WIN 10,0,2,54
StandAlone
```

[image]

Comment: Flagging for moderator attention should be done only when reporting serious issues with the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, What you downloaded off of the Adobe site is not Flash 10.3. There are new builds of Flash 11 on Labs.

You will need more than the SWC and XML. You will also need to download and install the beta player. You will need to test in browser as the player in Flash Pro is integrated, and there is no standalone for FP11 yet.

Most likely your DeviceCentral bug is due to the fact that Flash Player 11 is not supported (integrated) in CS4. This is the problem line in the player XML though it isn't going to help you much, just more of an FYI:

```
<player id="FlashPlayer11" version="13" asversion="3">
```

Keep in mind that anything related to any beta software from Adobe or elsewhere will be difficult to find any support for. Once the release version of Flash Player 11 is available, you will most likely see a large number of release information, tutorials, etc from Adobe.  This is just the nature of beta.

Comment: First of all thanx you very very very much for considering my question.

Comment: now "Flash Player 11" is just a tag name which is displayed in publish setting, i have downloaded playerglobal.swc from this link http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplatformruntimes/flashplayer10-3/flashplayer10-3_playerglobal_052011.swc which is for FlashPlayer10.3 and browser plugin is available from http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ this, then what is the procedure to get plugin for Flash IDE. and i just want to know that how can i export swf for Falshplayer 10.3. what should i do for that?????? is it possible with flash CS4???? again many thanx for answer. :)

Comment: "then what is the procedure to get plugin for Flash IDE.... is it possible with flash CS4??" No.
You will need to Publish, then test through browser, not use test-movie. 2 different concepts.

Comment: download the live version of playerglobal.swc here: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried with CS4, but there is a solution that works with CS5 and should work with CS4 as well. Have a look at the [Molehill from scratch with Adobe Flash CS 5](http://blog.kaourantin.net/?p=104) on Tinic Uro's blog.

[image: Molehill sample from Flash CS5 setup guide]

Comment: First of all Thanx for the answer, i have downloaded archive provided in blog, and pasted all the files in my Flashcs4 installation folder. and after that Restarted Flash CS4. now Flash player 11 is available in My Publish Settings but when i press CTRL + ENTER to export swf it opens Adobe Device Central CS4. i don't know why. have you any idea for that??